# YouTube livestream recorder linux?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

i there any option to record by nodejs or something else, livestream when is live on youtube? I know somethin like that is on twitch. i really need this because i play music copyright and all time youtube block my video :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're streaming using OBS or OBS studio, you can both stream and record to your local machine at the same time. It's simple as clicking "Start Record" button right after "Start Streaming" one.

The common thing is to have a key bind mapped to both of functions at the same time.